# WWW:Mechanize setvisible

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

Setting a radio button in the current form is simple:

```
$clone->set_visible([radio => '1']);
```

With an unknown number of radio buttons (probably 10 to 20) a loop should work:

```
while(1) {last if (!$clone->set_visible([radio => '1']));};
```

However, though setvisible always returns 1. My guess is it only returns 0 when nothing is set at all. But if even one field is set, it can get "re-set".

How do i stop after all radios are set? Or do i need to determine how many there are first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all inputs you need first:

```
my @radio_inputs = $mech->find_all_inputs(
    type       => 'radio',
);
```

Comment: Ah, so instead of using set_visible(), it's better to use find_all_inputs, and use field(), to set them manually:  foreach($clone->find_all_inputs(type => 'radio')){$clone->field($_->name, '1');}